# framer motion exit animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, framer-motion

framer-motion exit animations doesn't work in this code , Now according to framer-motion docs direct children should

have unique and stable keys in order for
the animations to work properly , I tried strings for the key it didn't work

so how can i do that here

thanks in advance

```
import CarouselP1 from "../carousel/carouselP1";
import { MdKeyboardDoubleArrowDown } from "react-icons/md";
import { MdKeyboardDoubleArrowUp } from "react-icons/md";
import { motion, AnimatePresence} from "framer-motion";

const ProjectCard1 = ({ images }) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const handleExpand = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-col space-y-3">
      <CarouselP1 images={images} />
      <div className=" flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-96 max-w-80">
        <p className=" "></p>
      </div>
      <button
        className="flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer"
        onClick={handleExpand}
      >
        <span className="pr-2">Details</span>
        {expanded ? (
          <MdKeyboardDoubleArrowUp className="mt-1" />
        ) : (
          <MdKeyboardDoubleArrowDown className="mt-1" />
        )}
      </button>
      {expanded && (
        <AnimatePresence>
        {expanded && (
          <motion.div
            
            initial={{ height: 0, opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ height: "15rem", opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ height:'0', opacity: '0' }}
            transition={{duration: 0.6, ease: "easeInOut"}}
            className="flex rounded-lg items-center justify-center w-48 bg-sky-200"
          >
            <ul>
              <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
              <li>3</li>
              <li>4</li>
              <li>5</li>
              <li>6</li>
            </ul>
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>)}


      <button className="w-18 h-10 p-2 bg-sky-400 rounded-lg">
        <a href=""></a>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectCard1;
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: I think `AnimatePresence` should not be conditionally rendered.

Comment: I didn't notice that , thank you